# How do I access the theme palette from within a component?

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to build a component that renders a `div` that displays an error.

```
function ErrorDiv(props) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Typography>{props.message}</Typography>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

I want to style the `<Card>` such that the background color is `palette.error.main`, and `<Typography>` such that the font color is white.

However, I'm not sure how I can access the theme colors. Is there a `palette` variable that is exposed? Or should I export individual colors as strings in my theme-creating module, and import the color for use here?

Answer (score 7):

Here are links to the documentation on this

- [CSS in JS](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/)
- [Accessing the Theme in a Component](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component)

Here is an example using withStyles:

```jsx
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const styles = theme => ({
  card: {
    background: theme.palette.error.main,
    color: '#fff'
  }
})

function ErrorCard({ classes }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
          Something went wrong!!
        </Typography>
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
}
export default withStyles(styles)(ErrorCard)
```

[Live example on Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zx5okn9m33?module=%2Fdemo.js)

Answer (score 6):

Form the docs: [Use Theme hook](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component)

```js
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/styles';

function DeepChild() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return <span>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</span>;
}
```

Not your typical use case but it is necessary for accessing an array of colour from the theme, for example